Verifying email via Postmark in Laravel results in 419 PAGE EXPIRED
My Laravel app works just fine, you can register, login etc. I recently added Postmark for email verifications, which works and emails are begin sent out.
My problem is however when I click on the "Verify Email Address" button that is sent out, I get redirected to my apps login page. Once I login I get redirected to 419 | PAGE EXPIRED and the users email is not verified.
I'm running on HTTPS and the login page is displayed even if I'm logged in when clicking on the verify button in the email but if I try to access the login page manually it redirects me to index.
What could be the issue, am I missing some configuration?

You're going to have to do some troubleshooting and figure out what's going on. A 419 is often a missing or mismatched CSRF token, used on POST requests. You'll need to open your browser's developer console when clicking the button and see where it's going and why it's throwing the 419.
